# Fitting a gamma frailty model in R (coxph)

Tags: r, error-handling

I have a [data set](http://yaap.it/paste/c11b9fdcfd68d02b#gIVtLrrme3MaiQd9hHy1zcTjRq7VsVQ8eAZ2fol1lUc=) with 6 clusters, each containing 48 (possibly censored, in which case `event = 0`) survival times. The `x` column contains a cluster-specific explanatory variable. I try to describe that data with a gamma frailty model as follows

```
 library(survival)

 mod <- coxph(Surv(time, event) ~ 
   x + frailty.gamma(cluster, eps=1e-10, method="em", sparse=0),
              outer.max=1000, iter.max=10000,
              data=data)
```

Here is the error message:

```
Error in if (history[2, 3] < (history[1, 3] + 1)) theta <- mean(history[1:2,  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to debug?

Comment: The help page for `frailty` says: "For Cox models the coxme package has replaced superseded this method."

Comment: Thanks for you commont @DWin. However, coxme fits Gaussian frailties, not gamma frailties.

Comment: no time to look into this further, but the place to look is in `"cfun"`, which is produced by `fraily.gamma()`:`FG <- frailty.gamma(data$cluster, eps=1e-10, method="em", sparse=TRUE);
FG["cfun"]`

Comment: @tim riffe: I would be interested to know a bit more when you have a minute ;-)

Comment: up voted just so you can recover some of the massive bounty...

Comment: I have asked the question to Terry Therneau (who is the author of coxph). I still need some time to think on his answer. I will post it here soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the answer I was given by Terry Therneau (the author of coxph).

I looked at your data:

```
> table(x, cluster)
     1  2  3  4  5  6
  0  0 48  0 48 48  0
  1 48  0 48  0  0 48
```

Your covariate "x" is perfectly predicted by the cluster variable.
If you fit a fixed effects model:
  coxph(Surv(time, event) ~ factor(cluster) +x)

then the "x" variable is declared redundant.  When the variance of the random effect is
sufficiently large, the same happens in the gamma model when the variance is sufficiently large.  Your model approaches this limit, and the solution fails.  As mentioned in the manual page, the coxme function is now preferred.

Last, your particular error message is caused by an invalid value for "sparse".  I'll add a check to the program.
You likely want "sparse=10" to force non-sparse computation.

Answer (score 8):

## Alternative solution :  Changing the variance factor

Changing the method of the variance of the random effect, seems to fix the problem.

e.g:

```
mod.aic <- coxph(Surv(time, event) ~ 
               x + frailty.gamma(cluster, eps=1e-10, method="aic", sparse=0),
             outer.max=1000, iter.max=10000,
             data=dat)

plot(survfit(mod.aic), col=4)
```

[image]

## ddd hoc solution: works if we remove one cluster

Maybe this don't answer exactly your question , but when I remove any cluster e.g:

```
par(mfrow=c(2,3))
res <- sapply( 1:6 , function(x) {
                      mod <- 
                        coxph(Surv(time, event) ~ 
                        x + frailty.gamma(cluster, eps=1e-10, method="em", sparse=0),
                        outer.max=1000, iter.max=10000,
                        data=subset(dat,cluster != x)
                        )
                     plot(survfit(mod), col=4,main= paste ('cluster', x, 'is removed'))
                     legend(10,1,mod$iter)
              })
```

the coxph converge and I have the same result for all samples.

[image]

I don't have enough information about your data for further analysis but I Tried to do some comparison between different clusters.

```
library(ggplot2
qplot(data = dat, x=time , y = x , facets= event~cluster)
```

[image]

I notice that 3 groups :

1. clusters 1,3,5 : events uniformally distributed
2. clusters 2 ,4 :  events just for small times.
3. cluster 6 :  amazing one ( only event 1)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. "method=aic" is however not standard and I have no idea how it performs compared to "method=em" which has been proven to give the same estimates as the EM algorithm...

Comment: So no way to use aic to select the variance even  with more explanation?

Comment: Sorry, I do not get the question... more explanation on what? By the way, +1 for your answer anyway

Comment: I would trust in 'method=aic' if I see simulation results showing it performs well. But, to me, it looks like an ad-hoc method... I have never seen anyone using that method in this context.

Comment: Thank you! Removing one cluster is indeed a good ad-hoc idea. If I could upvote twice, I would! I will post the answer of Terry Therneau (the author of coxph) very soon.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is with the data; you cannot separate cluster-specific effects from your `x` if all of the `x` are the same in each `cluster`.

Looking at the distribution of `x` in your data by cluster we can see this:

```
table(data$x,data$cluster)
     1  2  3  4  5  6
  0  0 48  0 48 48  0
  1 48  0 48  0  0 48
```

Which is I think what you mean by *cluster-specific explanatory variable*. This will be a problem in any model because `x` is collinear (I think that is the word) with `cluster`. Even trying the most basic model:

```
data$cluster<-as.factor(data$cluster)
mod <- coxph(Surv(time, event) ~ x + cluster, data=data)

Warning message:
In coxph(Surv(time, event) ~ x + cluster, data = data) :
  X matrix deemed to be singular; variable 5
```

The matrix is singular because there is no way to differentiate between the effects of `cluster` and `x`.

If you have no other variables besides `cluster` and `x`, then all you can really do is run the effect of the cluster alone:

```
data$cluster<-as.factor(data$cluster)
coxph(Surv(time, event) ~ cluster,data=data)

Call:
coxph(formula = Surv(time, event) ~ cluster, data = data)


          coef exp(coef) se(coef)     z       p
cluster2 1.070      2.92    0.382  2.80 5.1e-03
cluster3 0.499      1.65    0.384  1.30 1.9e-01
cluster4 1.705      5.50    0.365  4.68 2.9e-06
cluster5 2.058      7.83    0.370  5.56 2.7e-08
cluster6 4.415     82.69    0.399 11.06 0.0e+00
```

Consider that both `cluster1` and `cluster6` have the same value of `x`, and the hazard ratio between them is 83. Perhaps `cluster6` was different, perhaps `x` acts differently within `cluster6`: you can't tell the difference because of the way the data is structured.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. However, considering the "cluster effect" as random should allow to fit the model. By the way, changing "frailty.gamma(cluster, eps=1e-10, method="em", sparse=0)" into "frailty.gaussian(cluster, eps=1e-10, method="reml", sparse=0)" gives something. I really think that the problem comes from my R-code. Anyway, thx for your insight.

Comment: Good point. I have done a little debugging so far, and it seems that within one of the fitting functions inside `survival:::coxpenal.fit`, the `loglik` is returned as `NaN`, indicating that something was divided by zero within the C code. I suspect that the division by zero itself is caused by a "perfect fit" due to the structure of your data, but that is just a guess.